# buttonViewOption method from RecycleView.ViewHolder missing

Tags: android, contextmenu

I am trying to add options menu to a `RecycleView` row. Most examples require to add a listener at `onBindViewHolder` method, like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        binderHelper.bind(holder.swipeLayout, chat.getChatId());
        ...
        holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //buttonViewOption property does not exist
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
...
```

At [here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/create-options-menu-recyclerview-item-tutorial/) a very complete post about it.

My problem is that holder has no such property buttonViewOption at the time.

I can't find any documentation on buttonViewOption, not even as deprecated, yet it exists at many posts i found.
For sanity check i try this:

```
 RecyclerView.ViewHolder h;
 h.buttonViewOption.  //property does not exist
```

How to set the listener for the context menu?

Most likely i am missing  something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ViewHolder` implementation (`MyAdapter.ViewHolder`) will need to have a field `buttonViewOption` to work.

Refer to the [example you've referenced](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/create-options-menu-recyclerview-item-tutorial/) and search for `buttonViewOption` to see how it is done. In the example `R.id.textViewOptions` from the XML layout is mapped to the `buttonViewOption` field.

Your sanity check will never work, because as you have already discovered `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` simply does not have a `buttonViewOption` field - you'll need to extend this class and add this field.

Comment: Just couldn't see that. Tks